# Audio Recording with Appcelerator on Android

Tags: android, appcelerator, audio-recording, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile

I would like to record audio and then send the file to a webserver. I am using Titanium 1.8.2 on Win7.
The application I am woring on is both for Android and iphone and I do realise that Titanium.Media.AudioRecorder and Titanium.Media.AudioPlayer are for these purpose. Let's concentrate on android for a while.

On that platform you can achieve audio recording by creating an intent and then you handle the file in your application. See more [here](http://developer.appcelerator.com/blog/2011/02/launching-activities-and-using-content-uris-in-android.html). This implementation has a couple of drawbacks:

1. You cannot stay in your application (as a native audio recorder will start up)
2. You only get back an uri from the recorder and not the actual file.

Another implementation is done by [Codeboxed](http://www.codeboxed.com/2011/08/titanium-module-for-android-audio-recording/). This module is for recording an audio without using intents. The only problem that I could not get this working (along with other people) and the codeboxed team does not respond to anyone since last year.

So my question is: Do you know how to record audio on android without using an intent?
Thanks in advance.

Edit:

My problem with codeboxed's module:
I downloaded the module from  here.
I copied the zip file into my project directory.
I edited my manifest file with:

`<modules>
          <module platform="android" version="0.1">com.codeboxed.audiorecorder</module>
  </modules>`

When I try and compile I receive the following error:
    `[DEBUG] appending module: com.mwaysolutions.barcode.TitaniumBarcodeModule
    [DEBUG] module_id = com.codeboxed.audiorecorder
    [ERROR] The 'apiversion' for 'com.codeboxed.audiorecorder' in the module manifest is not a valid value.  Please use a version of the module that has an 'apiversion' value of 2 or greater set in it's manifest file
    [DEBUG] touching tiapp.xml to force rebuild next time:                         E:\TitaniumProjects\MyProject\tiapp.xml`
I can manage to recognise the module by editing the module's manifest file to this:
`
version: 0.1

description: My module

author: Your Name

license: Specify your license

copyright: Copyright (c) 2011 by Your Company

apiversion: 2

name: audiorecorder

moduleid: com.codeboxed.audiorecorder

guid: 747dce68-7d2d-426a-a527-7c67f4e9dfad

platform: android

minsdk: 1.7.0`

But Then again I receive error on compiling:
[DEBUG] "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_21\bin\javac.exe" -encoding utf8 -classpath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-8\android.jar;C:\Users\Gabor\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\1.8.2\android\modules\titanium-media.jar;C:\Users\Gabor\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\1.8.2\android\modules\titanium-platform.jar;C:\Users\Gabor\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\1.8.2\android\titanium.jar;C:\Users\Gabor\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\1.8.2\android\thirdparty.jar;C:\Users\Gabor\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\1.8.2\android\jaxen-1.1.1.jar;C:\Users\Gabor\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\1.8.2\android\modules\titanium-locale.jar;C:\Users\Gabor\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\1.8.2\android\modules\titanium-app.jar;C:\Users\Gabor\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\1.8.2\android\modules\titanium-gesture.jar;C:\Users\Gabor\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\1.8.2\android\modules\titanium-analytics.jar;C:\Users\Gabor\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\1.8.2\android\kroll-common.jar;C:\Users\Gabor\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\1.8.2\android\modules\titanium-network.jar;C:\Users\Gabor\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\1.8.2\android\ti-commons-codec-1.3.jar;C:\Users\Gabor\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\1.8.2\android\modules\titanium-ui.jar;C:\Users\Gabor\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\1.8.2\android\modules\titanium-database.jar;C:\Users\Gabor\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\1.8.2\android\kroll-v8.jar;C:\Users\Gabor\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\1.8.2\android\modules\titanium-xml.jar;C:\Users\Gabor\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\1.8.2\android\android-support-v4.jar;C:\Users\Gabor\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\1.8.2\android\modules\titanium-filesystem.jar;C:\Users\Gabor\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\1.8.2\android\modules\titanium-android.jar;E:\TitaniumProjects\MyProject\modules\android\com.mwaysolutions.barcode\0.3\barcode.jar;E:\TitaniumProjects\MyProject\modules\android\com.mwaysolutions.barcode\0.3\lib\zxing.jar;E:\TitaniumProjects\MyProject\modules\android\com.codeboxed.audiorecorder\0.1\audiorecorder.jar;C:\Users\Gabor\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\1.8.2\android\kroll-apt.jar;C:\Users\Gabor\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\1.8.2\android\lib\titanium-verify.jar;C:\Users\Gabor\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\1.8.2\android\lib\titanium-debug.jar" -d E:\TitaniumProjects\MyProject\build\android\bin\classes -proc:none -sourcepath E:\TitaniumProjects\MyProject\build\android\src -sourcepath E:\TitaniumProjects\MyProject\build\android\gen @c:\users\gabor\appdata\local\temp\tmpbqmjuy
[ERROR] Error(s) compiling generated Java code
[ERROR] E:\TitaniumProjects\MyProject\build\android\gen\com\petosoft\myproject\MyProjectApplication.java:44: cannot find symbol

symbol  : class AudiorecorderBootstrap

location: package com.codeboxed.audiorecorder

```
    runtime.addExternalModule("com.codeboxed.audiorecorder", com.codeboxed.audiorecorder.AudiorecorderBootstrap.class);

                                                                                        ^
```

1 error

Comment: What is the problem with Codeboxed module?

Answer (score 3):

An updated audio recorder module which works with Titanium SDK 2.1+ can be found [http://vocalrank.com/audiorecorder](http://vocalrank.com/audiorecorder/):

Comment: Is there a any free version, a sample solution, or something more?